# Should [alternate-class-feature] be merged with [class-feature]?

Tags: discussion, tags

My question/suggestion is pretty straightforward. The [alternate-class-feature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-class-feature) tag seems to be very narrow and rarely used, and it has no tag info so it's not clear how it's different from the existing and more commonly used [class-feature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-feature) tag.

Should the [alternate-class-feature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-class-feature) tag be merged with [class-feature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-feature)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, the tags should remain separate.

In 3.5 and Pathfinder, at least, ACFs are their own thing, with [their own rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm) that differ from the rules for normal class features.  People [collect lists of them](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?444354-3-5-Alternative-Class-Features-(ported-from-Wizards-community-boards)), they have [their own header in rules docs](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/advancedCoreClasses.html), they generally appear in a different chapter in source books from regular class features, etc.

In short, ACFs are their own topic, and it's useful to have a category about them.  It's easy to imagine questions that are specifically *about* the rules for ACFs, like:

- Can you trade away the same class feature twice for two different ACFs?
- If you gain a class feature as an ACF, can you then trade it away again for a *different* ACF?

(I'm honestly surprised neither of these questions is already on the site.)

It's reasonable to have a tag in place for questions like this.

Comment: Someone familiar with them should add some tag info making it clear what ACFs are, then :P

Comment: @V2Blast Made a go at it.  I've never edited a tag wiki before, so would appreciate some eyes on it and any fixes it needs.

Comment: @A_Soo: Looks good! I imagine the tag might also be useful for whatever form the revised ranger ends up taking, since Crawford and co. have said that if/when it gets published, it'll be a list of alternate class features to the PHB ranger (not a whole separate class).